# How can I enable editing on a specific row on a Dash DataTable

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I want to enable modifications on a specific row on a dash Datatable, so far we can enable editing by column, but I don't want to enable editing  on the whole column, I just want to enable it on a specific row.
I can highlight the row using `style_data_conditional`:

```
style_data_conditional = [
                {
                    "if": {"column_id": x, "row_index": 2},
                    "backgroundColor": 'red',
                    "cursor": "pointer",
                }
                for x in df.columns[2:]
            ]
```

But I want to make this row also editable.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this?  the answer below looks a bit like a css hack, but I would like to see if there is a way to accomplish it using the native Dash library.

Answer (score 0):

One approach it so make the whole `DataTable` editable and make specific rows not editable using css.

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv")

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id="table",
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict("records"),
    editable=True,
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When `DataTable` is not editable a `td` contains a div with the cell text inside. When it's editable the div with cell text has its opacity set to `0` and an input with the cell value is added.

We can add some `css` to remove this input and set the `opacity` of the div with the cell value to `1` for `td` elements where the `data-dash-row` attribute does not equal a certain row number:

```
td:not([data-dash-row="2"]) div.input-cell-value-shadow {
  opacity: 1 !important
}

td:not([data-dash-row="2"]) input {
  display: none;
}
```

So the styles above make it so only the third row of the `DataTable` is editable.